# Running Maths calculations across multiple groupby results in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do some Maths, using values from the results of two different `groupby`s. I have one series which includes `ID`, `Project` and `Hours` (**Hours**). The other series contains `ID`, `Project` and `Cost` (**Costs**).

**What I am trying to do:**

For each `ID` and `Project` pair in **Hours**, divide the `Hours` value by the total `Hours` for that `ID`. Then multiply that value by that `ID`s `Cost` in the **Costs** table.

For example, the forumula for the first ID-Project pair in the tables below would be:

`39 / (39 + 220) * 35.286 = 5.31`

Then:

`220 / (39 + 220) * 35.286 = 29.97`

Then:

`187 / 187 * 91.24 = 91.24`

And so on.

**Hours** ~ Hours by Project & ID (result of `groupby` with `ID` and `Project` being indexes):

```
                        Hours
ID      Project 
100001  413040-00140    39.0
        415012-00006    220.0
100002  705012-99999    187.5
100003  405012-15342    2.0
        418005-00023    144.0
```

**Costs** ~ Cost by ID (result of `groupby` with `ID` being index):

```
        Cost
ID  
100001  35.285835
100002  91.241904
100003  617.051535
```

**What I want:**

```
ID      Project         Allocated Costs
100001  413040-00140    5.31
        415012-00006    29.97
100002  705012-99999    91.24
100003  405012-15342    8.45
        418005-00023    608.60
```

If I filter these `groupby`s down to one `ID`, I can get it working with:

`Hours / Hours.sum() * float(Costs.values[0][0])`

But I need to do this for all `ID`s

Comment: that's just a simple merge between two dataframes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: @Steven Thanks. I will take a look. Although looks like the below answer answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) with `sum` per first level of `MultiIndex` and last multiple by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
df1['Allocated Costs']=df1['Hours'].div(df1['Hours'].sum(level=0), level=0).mul(df2['Cost'])
print (df1)
                     Hours  Allocated Costs
ID     Project                             
100001 413040-00140   39.0         5.313311
       415012-00006  220.0        29.972524
100002 705012-99999  187.5        91.241904
100003 405012-15342    2.0         8.452761
       418005-00023  144.0       608.598774
```

EDIT:

For last pandas version use:

```
df1.groupby(level=0)['Hours'].sum()
```

instead:

```
df1['Hours'].sum(level=0)
```

Comment: I think that works! Thank you so much. Does being able to come up with something like that so quickly just come with experience?